# "/home partition" after formating and reinstalling Ubuntu 18.04 on "ext4 /"

Tags: home-directory

if i install ubuntu 18.04 on a fresh disk by creating

EFI Partition 500mb
EXT 4 / Partition 100GB  (sda2)
EXT 4 /home Partition 100GB (sda3)

after some time if i format EXT4 / Partition (sda2) and fresh install Ubuntu 18.04 on it.

What will happen? will it create a home folder in sda2 or it will leave my /home in sda3? will i loose my data on /home (sda3)?

Comment: It will leave /home alone. Mount it at /home and do not format it. This is certainly a duplicate

Comment: In my first stage I will create 1. EFI 2. ext4 / 3. ext4 /home. In my second stage I will touch only ext 4 /.. I will format it and create ext4 / and install Ubuntu on it. I observed that when in past I only created EFI & ext 4 / partitions.. I saw /home folder in this by default.

Comment: IMHO you should **always** back up your data first. Even with the best intentions, accidents happen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you describe is my SOP.

Do a backup, you are one ticked box away from losing it all.

When you go to do the fresh install, select "something else" option in the installer.

Tell it to use your / partition, mount it at /, and tick the format box.

Tell it to use your /home partition, mount it at /home, *do not tick the format box*.

Tell it to use swap if you have a swap partition.

Then proceed with the install.